# Creating a Stripe Charge with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, stripe-payments

I have a working piece of code below, I was wondering if it is possible to make a stripe charge within the "successful token" of the checkout process? All the code below is working, I was just wondering where I would insert the code that creates the acctuall charge.

```
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"</script>

    <button id="payment-button" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Pay With Card</button>

    <script>
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'mykeyhere',
      image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function(token) {
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
        // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
        document.getElementById("book-appointment-submit").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("payment-button").style.display="none";
      }
    });

    document.getElementById('payment-button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      // Open Checkout with further options:
      handler.open({
        name: 'DenchCodeLTD',
        description: '2 widgets',
        zipCode: true,
        currency: 'gbp',
        amount: 2000
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation:
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
      handler.close();
    });
    </script>

<!-- End Of Stripe Payment -->

<button id="book-appointment-submit" type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="display:none">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    <?php
        echo (!$manage_mode) ? $this->lang->line('confirm')
                : $this->lang->line('update');
    ?>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a charge within the JS itself. Charging a customer with Stripe is a two-step process.

**Step 1:** You collect a customer's credit card information with Checkout, it is then sent to Stripe. You get back a token. That's what you're doing in your code above.

**Step 2:** You have to take this token and pass it to your backend, then tell Stripe to make a charge with it, or save it to a customer to be charged later. You will need a script on your server (PHP, Ruby, etc) to handle this step.

Some short examples of the second step are here: https://stripe.com/docs/charges

Inside your `token: function(token) { }` callback at the minimum you'll want to grab the `token.id`, append it to and `.submit()` a `<form></form>` surrounding your Checkout button.

If you want something a little more complex, you could pass the token id to your backend via an AJAX request and then relay the success or failure of the charge request back to the user.

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom